# How can I make a class, with a member variable that contains unique pointers, copy assignable?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, unique-ptr

I have a class (PlayerCharacter) that contains a map which in turn contains unique pointers. I have another class (Party) which should contain multiple instances of this first class. When I try to implement a constructor for Party that takes an instance of PlayerCharacter and copies it into the first element of a vector I get multiple errors (using g++) which are too long to put into this question.

I believe the error arises because BaseCharacter, and therefore PlayerCharacter, is not copy-assignable due to the unique pointers. How can I implement a complete copy constructor for this class?

MCVE below

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

enum class EQUIPMENT_SLOT {
    HEAD
};
class WeaponItem {};
class ClothingItem{};
class BaseCharacter {
    private:
        std::map<EQUIPMENT_SLOT, std::pair<std::unique_ptr<WeaponItem>, std::unique_ptr<ClothingItem>>> _equipment;
};
class PlayerCharacter : public BaseCharacter {};
class Party {
    private:
        std::vector<PlayerCharacter> _party_members;
    public:
        // Addition of this constructor causes errors to appear
        Party(PlayerCharacter player){
            this->_party_members.clear();
            this->_party_members.push_back(player); // This line is the problem - commenting it out compiles fine
        };
};
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use `shared_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr` or use shared_ptr in Party ctor and vector

Comment: @WaeCo Well that depends on whether they want a deep copy or a shallow copy.

Comment: This depends on what creating a copy of `PlayerCharacter` should mean. Should it copy the `WeaponItem` and `ClothingItem`? Then make copies in the `BaseCharacter` copy constructor. Should it point to the same items? Then `std::shared_ptr` or just a value might be a better way to store them. Should you not be able to copy a `PlayerCharacter` at all? Then your `std::vector` should hold a pointer or `refererence_wrapper` to `PlayerCharacter`.

Comment: @JosephMansfield they are in turn derived from a base class, so I presume that means they need deep copy

Comment: Are you quite sure that `party_members` shouldn't hold pointers?

Comment: @Kvothe Whether you want a deep copy or not depends on whether copying a `BaseCharacter` should give the new `BaseCharacter` its own `WeaponItem` and `ClothingItem` objects, rather than share them with the original `BaseCharacter`.

Comment: I assume that you actually do not want to copy the character (I understand it's the game's equivalent of a person). You want to hold logical *references* (perhaps C++ (smart(weak?)) pointers) to it.

Comment: Thanks for the responses - they've made me realise that I don't need to use `std::unique_ptr` to hold `WeaponItem` and `ClothingItem` anymore (that's a relic left from a previous attempt and is needlessly confusing it now). `party_members` should hold instances of `PlayerCharacter` but it should be the only instance of that character so that's the place where I should be using `std::unique_ptr`. I'll remove the question shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're holding items in a unique_ptr, it normally implies that you're not looking to copy them. If you want to copy them you'll have to provide the mechanism to do so:

```
struct my_thing {
};

using my_thing_ptr = std::unique_ptr<my_thing>;

struct my_container
{
  my_container() {}

  // the presence of _thing will implicitly delete copy constructor 
  // and copy operator so we need to provide them. 
  // Since we're defining copy operators, these will disable 
  // the automatic move operators so we need to define them too!

  my_container(const my_container& rhs)
  : _thing { rhs._thing ? new thing { *(rhs._thing) } : nullptr }
  {}

  my_container(my_container&& rhs) = default;

  my_container& operator=(const my_container&& rhs) {
    auto tmp = rhs;
    swap(tmp, *this);
    return *this;
  }

  my_container& operator=(my_container&& rhs) = default;

  // and an implementation of swap for good measure
  void swap(my_container& other) noexcept {
    using std::swap;
    swap(_thing, other._thing);
  }


  my_thing_ptr _thing;

};
```

Comment: Great answer! I was about to delete the question because I found I should have been doing things differently from the beginning but I'll leave it here now so your answer can help others

Comment: where is the delete question?

Comment: I meant I was about to remove the question I asked as it was no longer relevant for me

Comment: ok, so you'll be using shared_ptr<PlayerCharacter> ? sensible.